# Convert a date MM/DD/YYYY to a seven digit number

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the data like:

```
Completed Date       <\t>    Date<br>
02/12/2014           <\t>       2456701<br>
02/20/2014    <\t>              2456709
```

I found the way to convert a Date to Completed Date : `TO_DATE(Date,'J')`
I would like to convert a Completed Date into a Date using oracle DB function. Help me please.

Comment: If you know what J does, simply do the reverse. Use to_char.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do the vice-versa, **TO_DATE** and **TO_CHAR**.

To convert **Julian days to DATE**:

```
SQL> SELECT to_date(2457122, 'J') dt FROM dual;

DT
---------
09-APR-15
```

To convert **DATE into Julian days**:

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'J') dt FROM dual;

DT
-------
2457122
```